# Possible to use zxing in Silverlight (for windows phone)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, zxing

is it possible to use the c# port of zxing in a Windows Phone 7 project?

I've tried a couple of things but zxing makes use of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` while that doesn't exist in Silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an .Net port of the [ZXing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) at http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/ that supports Silverlight and
Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

System.Drawing.Bitmap isn't implemented on WP7 in this ctp.

I thought you might be interested in checking out [this](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/03/windowsphone-barcode/) demo of something that has been done with QR codes on the phone.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out the example! Looks promising!